# Obtaining maximum light from IR led for distance sensing

Tags: led, current

I'm working on a project and I'm using IR LEDs and photodiodes to measure the reflected signal. At the moment the IR LEDs are always on and drawing 100mA.

It works really well except for times when there's ambient light from either the sun or inside lighting. Is not a great deal but it makes moves or drowns out particular Tigger points. If the distance is small then there's not really a problem.

So I thought , as I don't really need the IR LEDs to be constantly on due to only reading them every 1ms, that I could pulse the IRs on when needed take the reading then turn them off.

Because of the pulse it means I can go up to the peak current value of 1A. Instead of the maximum of 100mA continuous..

The data sheet says for peak current of 1A

Conditions--Pulse Width≦100μs and Duty≦1%

So I understand this as it can be on for 1A for a maximum of 100us but must have 10ms gap between pulses if the pulse is on for 100us....

So I would like to know if my understanding is correct and that by using this pulsing techique it will give a stronger signal to remove ambiguities from the reading caused by ambient light

Comment: You are a bit off on your calculations... 100us = .1ms. Thus, a 1% duty cycle with a 100us pulse width would be .1ms ON followed by 9.9ms OFF. (.1ms * 100 = 10ms is total cycle time)
This would definitely increase the strength of the LED when it is on, if you believe that would solve your issue. (that is, the receiver is filtering out sun and ambient light, just not "seeing" the IR LED light because it is dim) Also of note, is that most all LED based communications (be it a remote or sensor) also have some modulation in the signal to ensure they are receiving the correct LED signal...

Comment: Filters might be better. Look at the Wii. It uses an IR camera and a few ir leds (or candles!) to work. Both have filters for the correct wavelength.

Comment: Thanks Kurt for pointing the mistake out, I had forgot to multiply by 100. Fixed now. My thinking is that the stronger IR will be strong enough to overcome the sun or ambient light, and so the ambient light would always be in the range which the IR led would never cause if that makes sense.

Comment: I think that the best thin is to use a Fresnel Lens to collimate the "light" of the LED but of course this depends from the geometry of your apparatus. Furthermore you should filter the photodiode because it can absorb light with shorter wavelength and so all the visible wavelength, you can do this with a BP filter a simple one is a floppy disk disk!